# What is the best Windows Media Center Extender?

Tags: windows-media-center, media-center-extender

What is the best Windows Media Center Extender?  I am debating if I should get an extender or hook directly to my video card.  The video card method is going to be a pain to control and many of the remotes aren't that good.  Is there a really good extender out there with a good remote as well as support for HDMI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use my xbox 360 and it works well enough for me.  It keeps my big noisy PC away from my TV watching experience.

Comment: The 360 is easily the best media center extender. Plus you get a free gaming system with it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's the best by any stretch of the imagination, but I use the Apple TV. It works with anything that iTunes works with, so that includes Windows.

Its really easy to use, syncs with iTunes wirelessly and has a huge library of downloadable content, rentable, purchaseable, everything.

Comment: Does it work with Windows Media Center?

Comment: Ah, um, probably not... heh. I didn't fully understand that when you said media center extender that you were specifically referring to Windows Media Center.